# XML Schema Augmentation

Tags: java, xml, schema

Trying to understand how XML Schema Augmentation works.

Quote from this link:
https://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-xmlschema-1-20010502/

> 2.1 Overview of XML Schema
>   An XML Schema consists of components such as type definitions and element declarations. These can be used to assess the validity of well-formed element and attribute information items (as defined in [XML-Infoset]), and furthermore may specify augmentations to those items and their descendants. **This augmentation makes explicit information which may have been implicit in the original document, such as normalized and/or default values for attributes and elements and the types of element and attribute information items.**

From this link:
https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/x-javaxmlvalidapi/#validation

> Some schemas do more than validate. As well as providing a true-false answer to the question of whether a document is valid, they also augment the document with additional information. For example, they can provide default attribute values. **They might also assign types like int or gYear to an element or attribute. The validator can create such type-augmented documents and write them onto a javax.xml.transform.Result object.**

So I would assume that if I validate a XML document against a schema it will produce a augmented XML document:

```
<thisIsAstring>Abc</thisIsAstring>
```

becomes

```
<thisIsAstring type="String">Abc</thisIsAstring>
```

*Above an assumption as I haven't got it to work yet.*

When I execute the below code, the result contains more or less the same as source.

```
    DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    dbf.setNamespaceAware(true); 
    DocumentBuilder parser = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
    Document document = parser.parse(new InputSource(new StringReader(inputMessage)));
    SchemaFactory factory = SchemaFactory.newInstance(XMLConstants.W3C_XML_SCHEMA_NS_URI); 
    Source schemaSource = new SAXSource(new InputSource(new StringReader(inputSchema)));            
    Schema schema = factory.newSchema(schemaSource);
    Validator validator = schema.newValidator();
    DOMResult result = new DOMResult();
    DOMSource source = new DOMSource(document);
    validator.validate(source,result);
```

Why is result not augmented ? What am I missing ?

Answer (score 0):

The extra properties added to the document tree by the schema validator (the PSVI properties) are not attributes. The way they are added and the way you access them varies from one schema processor to another, and you may need to request this processing using the API. For Xerces, there is information on how to access the PSVI here:

http://xerces.apache.org/xerces2-j/faq-xs.html

If you use Saxon as your schema validator, you can capture the result as a tree in which the NodeInfo.getSchemaType() method returns the type annotation of a node (however, Saxon does not deliver a complete PSVI, only the part of the PSVI mandated by the XSLT and XQuery specifications.)